# How can I pass Mocha switches when calling Truffle?

Tags: truffle, mocha

When calling `truffle test some_test.js`, I would like to pass [Mocha switches](https://mochajs.org/#usage).

For example: `truffle --no-colors test some_test.js` works fine.

However: `truffle --reporter json-streams test some_test.js` doesn't.

To my understanding, it should get Mocha to generate all the output in JSON format.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I think I found the answer [here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration#mocha)...

Answer (score 3):

I can do it by adding this to the Truffle configuration file (`truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js`):

```
mocha: {
    useColors: false,
    reporter: "json"
}
```

Available reporters are described [here](https://mochajs.org/#reporters).

Comment: But this is restricted to general configuration. What if a I want to use some mocha settings for my dev environment but others for CI?

Answer (score 1):

Truffle uses Mocha programatically. So, the `Mocha` class constructor shows the full options. Truffle v5.1.9 seems to use Mocha v5.2.0 and the constructor code for this version can be found here.

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v5.2.0/lib/mocha.js#L83

Which shows

```js
 * @class Mocha
 * @param {Object} options
 */
function Mocha(options) {
  options = options || {};
  this.files = [];
  this.options = options;
  if (options.grep) {
    this.grep(new RegExp(options.grep));
  }
  if (options.fgrep) {
    this.fgrep(options.fgrep);
  }
  this.suite = new exports.Suite('', new exports.Context());
  this.ui(options.ui);
  this.bail(options.bail);
  this.reporter(options.reporter, options.reporterOptions);
  if (typeof options.timeout !== 'undefined' && options.timeout !== null) {
    this.timeout(options.timeout);
  }
  if (typeof options.retries !== 'undefined' && options.retries !== null) {
    this.retries(options.retries);
  }
  this.useColors(options.useColors);
  if (options.enableTimeouts !== null) {
    this.enableTimeouts(options.enableTimeouts);
  }
  if (options.slow) {
    this.slow(options.slow);
  }
}
```

You can find options like `ui`, `bail`, `reporter`, `reporterOptions`, `timeout`, `retries`, `useColors`, `enableTimeouts` and so on.

More detailed meaning of these options can be inferred from the API documentation of Mocha class located at https://mochajs.org/api/mocha.

For example, API documentations for methods such as [`bail()`](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#bail), [`retries()`](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#retries), [`enableTimeouts()`](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#enableTimeouts), or [`timeout()`](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#timeout) show more details on corresponding options.